# TestNG code compliling error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm new to java/testNg I'm trying to run code that you enter a persons number and then that user will be added into the database via the webpage. Although the code allows me to enter the msisdn the actions are not executed via the webpage.
The following is my code :

```
package firsttestng1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    //adding subscriber class
    public class subscribers {
    public String baseUrl = "http://testpage.ie";
    public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    public String msisdn;


//set members number
    public void setSubscriber(String subscribrNmbr){
        msisdn=subscribrNmbr;

    }
//get subscribers number
    public String getSubscriber(){
        return msisdn;

    }

    //adding subscriber method which should enter the subscribers number once it is entered 
    public void addMembers(){   
        waitForElement("[title=\"Run\"]",false);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Policy")).click();  
        waitForElement("[title=\"SPCM\"]",false);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Memebers")).click();    
        waitForElement("[title=\"Memembers Mgmt\"]",false);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("MemberMgmt")).click();  
        waitForElement("[title=\"Subscribers\"]",false);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Members Page")).click();    
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("add_label")).click(); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("subscriberIdentifier.msisdn")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("subscriberIdentifier.msisdn")).sendKeys(""+getSubscriber());
        driver.findElement(By.id("subscriberIdentifier.imsi")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("subscriberIdentifier.imsi")).sendKeys(""+getSubscriber());
        driver.findElement(By.id("subscriberIdentifier.imsi")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submitSubscriberButton_label")).click();
        if(isAlertPresent()){
            driver.switchTo().alert();
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        }













package firsttestng1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirsttestNGFile {


    //launch Firefox and enter login details
    @BeforeTest
    public void launchBrowser(){
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("test");  
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 


        }

//main method
     @Test
    private void addSubscriber() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        subscribers nwsubscriber = new subscribers();

        System.out.println("Enter misidn");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        nwsubscriber.setSubscriber(temp);


    }



    }


  <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="FirstTestNG1.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="AWTConsole">
        <java classname="bsh.util.AWTConsole" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="FirstTestNG1.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Did U started from working example ???

Comment: Where is your XML? please share that code..

Comment: I created my code from various examples,I've add the XML to my original question